# Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "-" at [5:17] error in BigQuery exercise

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, syntax-error, data-analysis

I`m working with an exercise from the Google Data Analysis Course, that asks me to write and execute the following query:

SELECT
station_name,
ridership_2013,
ridership_2014
ridership_2014-ridership_2013 AS change_2014_raw
FROM
bigquery-public-data.new_york_subway.subway_ridership_2013_present

but every time I try to run it, I get the same error:

Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "-" at [5:17]

I think that the error is the dash from the subtraction between ridership_2014-ridership_2013, but I'm not sure if it`s something from my keyboard or something else,

I'll appreciate some of your help on this,

Thank you!!

Comment: Try putting a space either side of the minus symbol

Comment: you are missing comma after first appearaance of `ridership_2014` in select statement!

Comment: Thank you!! the issue was the missing comma. Regards!!